# Compilation Error "! Missing \endcsname inserted" The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname

Tags: debugging

here's my thesis Latex files: http://www.mediafire.com/download/c7q8z4v6gv864rk/triet_thesis_clean.rar

Please help me to fix the error, I've tried all the things I can find with Google :( :

```
   ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
   <to be read again>
   \begingroup
   l.52 ...}intopreamble]Deobfuscation}{{4.1.1}{xii}}
   The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
   not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
   (D:\DH\Luan_Van_Tot_Nghiep\Latex\triet_thesis_test\LVTN.aux
```

Comment: Please show use some code ([Minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)).

Comment: On overleaf, I just deleted the cache and aux and other files. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have a wrong character in one of your labels:

```
\subsection{LLVM}
\label{subsec:LLVMDeobfuscation}
```

where, between `LLVM` and `Deobfuscation`, you have the Unicode character [U+200E (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK)](https://unicode-table.com/en/200E/) that somehow sneaked in.

Retype the label and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.
Could you tell me how you find out the reason :) ?

Comment: If you use the `\usepackage{underscore}` the '_' character in labels will cause this error. To fix this also use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Comment: I'm stuck with this error message, and I would love to know how I  go about fixing it?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Difficult to say without an example.

Comment: @egreg I don't think it's related. But I was wondering how you might go about finding bad "invisible" characters?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I copied the offending text and pasted on a multiconverter that shows every byte, for instance https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: @Cyrille Please make that an answer! It helped me a lot

Comment: Sure @Phani, but I have no recollection of where or how I came to this conclusion as it was so long ago. So I have little to add in my answer unfortunately. Glad its helped a few people though.

Answer (score 13):

For others if you have not tried to delete all the generated files from pdflatex and bibtex, then do that before any other changes, because it could be a compilation error.

Comment: Urgh, thanks... Turns out my `clean` Makefile target was insufficient

Answer (score 3):

I never wrote Vietnamese and don't know if it can be done with `pdflatex`. However, if I use `xelatex` instead and

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{vietnam}%% xelatex is by default utf8
\usepackage{fontspec}%% load unicode fonts
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{suthesis-2e}
\begin{document}
 ...
```

I'll get a proper output with out any errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to write my thesis in Vietnamese :( . Could you help me a little bit further?

Comment: as I wrote: use may preamble and then run `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. Every editor ahopuld have such a button or topix for `xelatex`

Comment: No, the OP probably won't get proper output: the error is caused by a spurious (invisibile) character in a label and probably all references to it will not be resolved.

Comment: I get all references right with `xelatex`

Comment: You get references right provided you build `\ref{...}` by copy-pasting from the argument of `\label`. If you type directly `\ref{subsec:LLVMDeobfuscation}` you *can't* get a correct reference.

Comment: I did _not_ used copy & paste!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `\usepackage{underscore}` the '_' character in labels will cause this error.

To fix this add the following: `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

### Edit

Here's an example to show the fix works.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% try commenting out the packages below
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

The banana figure, see Figure \ref{banana_two}.

This is going to be a line with an underscored filename: Banana_getting_unpealed.png

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Bananas.}
    \label{banana_two}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does this help- what does it do?

Comment: I don't remember what I was trying to do or fix - just that this did the trick. Underscores can cause a "Missing $ inserted." error, adding both the underscore and babel packages fixes this.

Comment: I removed all underscores in my bibtex and that was quite tedious.

Comment: Pure Genius.  I haven't seen a kludge of this beauty in 20 years.  I've written kludgier myself but mine were not things of beauty.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, malformed options in `\includegraphics` (from the graphicx package) will cause this error (`! Missing \endcsname inserted.`). One example is forgetting `width=`, thus `\includegraphics[1.0\textwidth]{filename}` instead of `\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{filename}`.

I am uncertain if this occurs in every case or just with particular documentclasses (beamer here) and in the presence of particular other packages.

Comment: Just found this out the hard way myself